# Installshield Installation with Multiple Releases with different redistributables

Tags: installshield

I'm trying to create an installshield installation with two releases. One that includes the .NET 4.0 client profile framework, and one that doesn't. Is this posible or does it have to be separate projects?

Answer (score 1):

In the Professional and higher editions, you can set release flags on the prerequisite and in your releases to either include or exclude the prerequisite from that build.

Comment: There is a missing story here though IMO.  It would be nice if IS could build 1 configuration that outputs both the EXE wrapped MSI and the MSI by itself.  This way they have the same PackageCode.  This scenario is often needed.